# jQuery hide image when I reach a div id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an image after 3 seconds of hitting a div id. It appears my if statement is giving me major issues..

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var topOfDiv = $("#entering-div").offset().top;
      $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfDiv) {
          console.log("top of div reached");
          setTimeout(function() {
              $('#quote-image').fadeOut();
          },3000);
        }
      });
    });
```

Can't figure out why the if statement is not being triggered.

## Console

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and include any errors you're getting

Comment: your code looks fine. since if-statement is not triggered, it means the condition it not met, console log your params before the if statement and perform some debugging yourself. Another thing I noticed in your code is that you are using jQuery and $ interchangebly, do you have only 1 version of jQ running?

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Oh shoot, I actually don't know. I posted my console output in the edits....

Comment: it looks like there are other js error that happened before your js code is even executed. hence your code is not running.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Hmmm ok, I have jQuery version: 1.12.4 but it says JQMigrate: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1? Would that be an issue?